# Подключение стилей

Tags: python, css, webapp2

Да. Вопрос, может, и простой, но тем не менее...

Проект работает на WebApp2. Там все стили после компиляции через App Engine работают.

Но если этот же самый проект запустить локально, то стили не подключаются. Открывал код страницы - проверял пути подключения и существование файлов - все также...

Но, не подключаются CSS-стили. В чем может быть проблема? Может есть еще способ посмотреть что-то?

Дополнение:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/src/css/main.css" type='text/css'/>-->
```

Comment: @Сергей, внес дополнение по подключению. У меня через **href**

Comment: @Сергей, тоже нет

Comment: настройки корневого пути и контекстного пути веб-приложения менялись? Вот ещё  — Я нашел проблему. Проблема в том, что я изменил контекстный путь для приложения, и браузер не может разрешить путь для статического контента.

Мне пришлось добавить префикс href "/{context-path}/css/styles.css" вместо "css/styles.css". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55910050/unable-to-serve-css-files-placed-in-src-main-resources-static-css-folder-to-cli